# Qt 5: Debug\release and Release\debug directories

Tags: qt, directory-structure, visual-studio-2010, project-structure

I use Qt 5.0.1 with Windows SDK 7.1. If I create a new application, the Kits page of the New app wizard offers to create Debug and Release directories:

```
Debug:   C:\Projects\MyProject-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_1_MSVC2010_32bit-Debug
Release: C:\Projects\MyProject-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_1_MSVC2010_32bit-Release
```

1) If I compile the app in Debug mode, Qt Creator creates two directories:

```
C:\Projects\MyProject-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_1_MSVC2010_32bit-Debug\debug
C:\Projects\MyProject-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_1_MSVC2010_32bit-Debug\release
```

The executable will be created in the former, `C:\...-Debug\debug`.

2) If I compile the app in Release mode, I will get another pair of directories:

```
C:\Projects\MyProject-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_1_MSVC2010_32bit-Release\debug
C:\Projects\MyProject-build-Desktop_Qt_5_0_1_MSVC2010_32bit-Release\release
```

In this case, the executable will be placed in the latter, `C:\...-Release\release`.

What is the logic behind this nested directory structure? When does the IDE use the directories `C:\...-Debug\release` and `C:\...-Release\debug`?

**UPDATE**

@phyatt pointed out that turning off [shadow building](http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.7/creator-glossary.html) in project settings eliminates the problem. The debug and release directories will be generated inside the project's source directory:

```
C:\Projects\MyProject\debug
C:\Projects\MyProject\release
```

Unfortunately, this doesn't answer the above question. Moreover, now the project settings page displays a warning:

> An incomplete build exists in C:\Projects\MyProject, which will be
>   overwritten.

Comment: Sounds like a minor bug. Maybe it is better to report this to qt-creator developers directly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are only using a single compiler, I would go into the Projects tab > Build > General > Shadow Build, and uncheck Shadow Build.

This will simplify the configuration and folder structure, and may fix the bug for you.

Maybe go in and do a build clean for good measure.

Hope that helps.

Comment: +1 Thank you! I turned off shadow building for both Release and Debug configurations. Unfortunately, I still don't understand the directory structure when shadow building is turned on.